# How to handle random access ifstream use? - position/offset/size issues

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing a Photoshop PSD file parser to extract some specific metadata. Skipping over possibly big chunks of irrelevant data suggests some random access. And I need to support PSB as well as PSD - PSB has the same basic file structure but with bigger limits and with some size fields as 64-bits.

With the [Photoshop file format specs.](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/) publicly available, this should be a trivial job, but I've never needed to worry about large files before, at least while using `ifstream`. I've always got away with ignoring `streampos` etc and just using `size_t` for file positions and offsets. I'm not getting away with that now.

I wasn't expecting that to be a big deal, and it isn't really, but it's turning out to be awkward and messy - I assume that means I'm fighting the library rather than doing what it expects.

First issue - there are three position/offset/size types...

- `streampos`
- `streamoff`
- `streamsize`

This seems unnecessary to me. A position in a file is an offset from the start. The size of a file is also the offset from the start to the end. That's why we specify positions, offsets and sizes in `vector` with the same type - `size_t`.

In fact the easiest way I've found to determine the size of a file gives me a `streampos` - seek to the end of the file and query the position...

```
myfile.seekg (0, ios::end);
streampos myfilesize = myfile.tellg ();
```

The `streampos` type is also an instance of a template class `fpos` (which using GCC 4.7.0 seems to be 16 bytes - I haven't checked whether I'm building 32-bit or 64-bit code but either way that seems oversize). Why not just use an integer type?

Some annoyances...

```
streampos p;
p++;               //  Error - streampos doesn't have operator++
p = p + 1;         //  Warning - ambiguous (using 1ul or 1ull doesn't seem to fix it)
```

Those warning issues happen with comparisons and elsewhere too.

Basically, I'm getting a lot of irritating noise to work around these - lot's of casts to `streampos` or `streamoff` etc.

I have the feeling I'm being an idiot and missing something obvious, but my Google-skills are failing me - I haven't found an example that shows what I'm doing wrong.

So - what am I doing wrong? Is there an idiomatic style to doing random access with position calculations that avoids all this noise?

Comment: Borderline asleep by now, so I'll leave this for someone else -- but to answer your last question -- no, at least not entirely, when you need to go low enough to be bothered with offsets, it just gets messy by definition.

Answer (score 0):

So far, what I've figured out is that...

- `std::streampos` isn't a simple integer because it may need to support large files on platforms that don't have 64 bit integer types as standard. In fact it almost certainly predates widespread support of 64 bit integers in compilers for PCs - [Borland C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B) gained them in version 5.02 for example, IIRC, in 1997 - not long before the first standard. The `long long` wasn't standard until C++11.
- `std::streamsize` and `std::streamoff` are both typedefs of integer types. However, `streamoff` is always a signed type. This is important for relative seeks, which may be backwards. I haven't found any requirements for whether `streamsize` must be signed or unsigned - I'm guessing it's at least possible for it to be unsigned.
- When adding or subtracting from `streampos`, you should always be adding or subtracting a `streamoff`. Typecast where needed, e.g. when adding or subtracting a literal number.
- As always, when something is messy, wrap the mess and hide it.